# Need regex help for matching names

Tags: regex

Let's say I have these three names

```
John Doe (p45643)
Le'anne Frank
Molly-Mae Edwards
```

I want to match
1) John Doe
2) Le'anne Frank
3) Molly-Mae Edwards

The regex I have tried is

```
(^[a-zA-Z-'^\d]$)+
```

but it isn't working as I am expecting.

I would like help creating a regex pattern that:

Matches a name from start to finish, and cannot contain a number. The only permitted values each "name" can contain is, [a-zA-Z'-], so if a name was 
`J0hn` then it shouldn't match

Comment: Would you allow names also starting and ending with `'` or `-`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, then you have a minor errors in your regex:

```
(^[a-zA-Z-'^\d]$)+
         ^-------^------Here
```

The `-` pointed above should be escaped or moved to the end since it works as a range character. The `+` is marking the group as repeated.

You can use this regex instead (following your previous pattern):

```
(^[a-zA-Z'^\d -]+$)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuzDLP/1)**

Update: for your comment. If you want to match separately, then you can use:

```
(\b[a-zA-Z'^\d-]+\b)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuzDLP/2)**

And if you only want to match string (not numbers), then you can use:

```
(\b[a-zA-Z'-]+\b)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuzDLP/3)**

Comment: Oh right, I see thanks. Well your regex is nearly correct, but for the first name, I wanted John Doe to be matched from the string "John Doe (p45643)". Also, I would want the the pattern to match it each name, not the full name. So the string "John Doe (p45643)" would match ["John", "Doe"]
Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: You maybe want to use boundary word (\b) except ^ and $ 
"John Doe (p45643)".match(/(\b[a-zA-Z'^\d -]+\b)/)

Comment: @AwesomeGuy, i've updated the answer with two more patterns

Answer (score 0):

You are using the anchors incorrectly. Based on the modifier it can match the whole string or a single line.
Try

```
/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/
```

Comment: based on you comment, you also want to match "John Doe (p45643)"
then use: /([a-zA-Z'-]+)(\s+[a-zA-Z'-]+)?/
The second group is optional becasue of the ?.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Djory Krache

The query I was looking for was

```
(\b[a-zA-Z'-]+\b)
```